# How do I include dependency file, put in target, into Java code using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, resources

I'm a little stuck because I'm not sure I'm going down the right path.

Currently, I have multiple projects - one project that distributes a .zip file containing several other files including an XML file and a JSON file. This is already in the Maven local repository we're using, and isn't an issue at the moment.

The problem is now we have another project that needs to use this file, at compile as well as runtime. So, we need to load this as a resource. However, including these files in the jar using:

```
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-scripts</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>mygroupidhere</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>myartifacthere</artifactId>
                                    <version>myversionhere</version>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <classifier>sources</classifier>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

does extract the required files to target/sources, and includes them in the top level directory of the built jar. However, I am struggling to actually *load these files* using the Java code in the project that it is in. This needs to be compatible with building (with unit tests) as well as at runtime from the jar file (in the jar, the files are placed in sources/ as one would expect).

I've tried using `Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("sources/examplefile"))` but the unit tests fail (at this point, it's in target/sources/examplefile, which works, but obviously won't work at runtime because it'll just be in sources/examplefile).

I've tried getResourcesAsStream from the class as well, which makes sense at runtime, but won't work in the unit tests because it'll be in target as it is taken from the dependency. The unit tests have to be compatible with the files in the dependency directly (so they're more like integration tests really), otherwise we do want this project to fail to build.

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: ``getClass().getResource("/path/to/the/embedded/file")``

Comment: @spi This does not work both on compile (when it is in target/sources) and at runtime (when it is in sources/)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bad design.

1. Create a maven artifact (jar file) with your resources and then add it as a dependency to your project. Have a simple class file in it as well (e.g `Loader`).

```java
package something;
public class Loader(){
}
```

2. Use this class as a starting point to load your resources: `something.Loader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/<whatever>")`

Comment: That was what we originally were doing, but we're refactoring it so that the java loader file (there's quite a lot of code in that, but yeah perhaps it should be separated out from the loader class...) doesn't have to be tied to the artifacts that are generated elsewhere.

Comment: If  you don't have an "in" (a loader class), you have to know where the file lies in the filesystem. Than you can start by getting an uri path using your own class `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("YourClass.class")` and then analyzing the uri. But it is a pain in the ass. Your class file could be inside a jar file or direct in the file system.
It should be easier if you can associate a known (fixed or per property or something) path to your resource.

Comment: Unfortunately this is going to be in multiple different places, so it probably does need a loader class in the artifact like you've said. Thanks

Comment: We ended up going with ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream which solved the issue. From our architectural point of perspective I think this works best. Thanks for the help!